# How to make spatial plot of irregular geographical data

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have `lat=[13.7,21,23.7,10.6,34.5,20.7,33.1,15.5]`
    `lon=[65.7,87.5,69.8,98.3,67,79.8,88.8,77.9]` and
    `val=[234,310,287,279,298,280,279,321]`

How can I make a spatial plot these data over map ? My code look like

```
lat=[13.7,21,23.7,10.6,34.5,20.7,33.1,15.5]
lon=[65.7,87.5,69.8,98.3,67,79.8,88.8,77.9]
val=[234,310,287,279,298,280,279,321]
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
m = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution=None,
        llcrnrlat=0, urcrnrlat=40,
        llcrnrlon=60, urcrnrlon=100, )
m.contourf(lon,lat,val)
```

Comment: Based on the items in `val`, you have 8 points to build a surface out of available data. If you want to use `meshgrid`, you need 8x8 values of `val`.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `contourf`, you need gridded data (i.e. if you have an 8x8 lon-lat grid, you need 64 z values). As you have only (lon,lat,z) triplets, it is better to use a [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) plot. However, Basemap does not have that function, but has an additional `tri` keyword for the `contourf` function:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import basemap

lat=np.array([13.7,21,23.7,10.6,34.5,20.7,33.1,15.5])
lon=np.array([65.7,87.5,69.8,98.3,67,79.8,88.8,77.9])
val=np.array([234,310,287,279,298,280,279,321])

#lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat) <-- do not use this

m = basemap.Basemap(projection='merc', resolution=None,
        llcrnrlat=0, urcrnrlat=40,
        llcrnrlon=60, urcrnrlon=100, )

##need to convert coordinates
x,y = m(lon,lat)

##add the `tri=True` kwarg
m.contourf(x,y,val, tri=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: result of above code]